# angular 4 component inheritance and "extending view"

Tags: angular, typescript, inheritance

When you do component inheritance in angular like

```
export class ChildComponent extends ParentComponent{}
```

You can get all the logic from the ParentComponent, but you have to implement the entire html again.

Say my ParentComponent's html looks like this

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="header"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
    <div class="footer"></div>
</div>
```

Is there a way I can "implement" the parent component where the child component view sort of implements only the "content" div?

for example

```
@Component({
   template:`<div class="content-of-child">...</div>`
})
 export class ChildComponent extends ParentComponent{}
```

so that the result will be

```
<div class="card">
        <div class="header"></div>
        <div class="content-of-child"></div>
        <div class="footer"></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

No you can't do like that but what you can do is split your parent component into 3 components and extend only 'content' component. But then again you will need to create New parent component where you will insert extended component.

Comment: is there no way around it? The example above is just simplified, I have extensive view logic around that "content" div

Comment: i understand but no way arround you can follow this issue https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11144

Comment: And i know that it makes a lot of pain :-)

Comment: So split into component header footer content -> Override content with content of child -> create new Parent

Comment: what about using ng-content and transclusion to achieve it?

Comment: @HanChe my bad. Updated answer

Comment: I've tried it, it only works with static views. So you can't loop stuff unless you look the entire thing. Still it's good to know about it :)

Comment: @HanChe :-) so you need to split and then override :-) Thanks for the feedback.